# $M^2<N^2$ if $M,N$ are two positive definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If $M,N$ are two positive definite matrix st. $M<N$, is that true that $M^2<N^2$?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)

Answer (score 2):

It is true if $NM=MN$;  $N+M$, $M-N$ are positive $M^2-N^2=(M+N)(M-N)=(M-N)(M+N)$ apply 2 in

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$ A = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 2\cr}, \ B = \pmatrix{2+\epsilon & 1\cr 1 & 3\cr} $$
which are positive definite, with
 $B > A$ if $\epsilon > 0$, but  $\det(B^2 - A^2) = -1 + 14 \epsilon + 5 \epsilon^2$, so for small positive $\epsilon$ (in fact $0 < \epsilon < (3\sqrt{6}-7)/5)$ we do **not** have $A^2 < B^2$.